# What is the c++ translation for 'textscan' function from Matlab?

Tags: c++, c, matlab, file-io, textscan

What is a simple translation in code for 'textscan' from matlab into C or C++?
I am using Ubuntu and I am trying to translate a Matlab code into C++.
Thank you very much.

Comment: no I think fscanf is similar to fscanf in matlab. Textscan in matlab searches for a format of code. it has some higher capabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the answer is not the same if you're using C or if you're using C++. These are different programming languages.

Matlab is a much higher-level language than C and C++. In Matlab `textscan` reads from files *or* strings. C and C++ have different mechanisms for that.

**To read from a file :**

In C, you should use the `FILE` object and its associated functions (fopen, fgets ...) from the header file : `stdio.h`.

In C++, you should use `std::ifstream` from the `<fstream>` header file. For formatted input use the `>>` operator.

**To read from a string :**

In C, you might want to look at the functions in the `string.h` header.

In C++, the better way is to use the `std::istringstream` class from the `sstream` header file.

Comment: Can you elaborate on reading file using ifstream and >>? How does ">>" work like matlab's textscan?

Answer (score 1):

It is `fscanf`. You will need to `#include <stdio.h>` and open `FILE` objects with `fopen` to use it.